# How to reduce deduction amount in salary

Tags: income-tax, india, income-tax-refund, mpf

For my 58333 Total anual CTC, these are total deductions

```
1800 - Company Contribution to PF
0167 - Group Personal Accident Insurance
0833 - Group Mediclaim Insurnace    
1042 - Gratuity
0200 - Professional Tax 
1800 - Provident Fund
4166 - Performance Linked Variable Incentive
1172 - Income Tax
```

from these

```
1800 - Provident Fund
4166 - Performance Linked Variable Incentive
```

are returnable.

I dont want insurance but company says it's compulsory for all employees.

Can someone please explain me

> Company Contribution to PF and Gratuity deduction

What are the tips to reduce such extra deduction. I want maximum on hand salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 aspects the **Salary** the company pays you and the **Cost** to the company which is higher than Salary.
In older days the companies would tell you the salary and you would decide to join on that basis, however given the current competition *quite a few companies* tell you **CTC** , i.e. Cost to Company. This number looks higher and most try to join only to realize that it is not true. Hence if you are comparing salaries to 2 companies, you have to leave out quite a few items.

> Company Contribution to PF

As per regulations, Employers are required to match the PF contributions by Employee to the extent of 12% of Basic. As a practise most organization deduct 12% of basic and deposit it with PPF Office. An equal amount contributed and deposited by Employee.

> Gratuity

As per regulations an organization must pay Gratuity after 5 years of completion of service at the rate of 15 days [last Drawn] Basic Salary for every year of Service completed. So if you leave after 5 years, you get 2.5 of Basic salary, if you leave after 8 years you get 4 of you Basic Salary

**Edit to Clarify the comment**
If your *salary* is Rs 1000, you pay a PF of Rs 100. The company pays a PF of Rs 100. Net you get Rs 900. Now what your company is saying is your *CTC* is Rs 1100, your PF deduction is Rs 100 and Company's contribution is Rs 100. You net is still Rs 900.

Comment: PF already gets deducted from employee's salary, why would `Company Contribution to PF` should be paid by employee, should it not be payable by company itself?